# Calling method after android listview is drawn

Tags: android, android-listview

how do I call my method after the drawing of listview is done

Answer (score 0):

Most actions in android are event based, so unless the method needs to be called as a part of the 'onCreate' method of the activity, it really should be in an event listener callback method.  For example, if you are drawing the listview in the onCreate method, simply call your desired method after.  If the listview is drawn at a later time, it should really be in response to a user event, and in that case, you could place both the listview and the desired method in the event callback.

Of course, without any sample code, its really hard to tell what the right answer is.  :)